# React Apollo Error: No more mocked responses for the query: mutation

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, graphql, apollo

**Intended outcome:**

MockedProvider should mock my createPost mutation.

**Actual outcome:**

```
Error: No more mocked responses for the query: mutation...
```

**How to reproduce the issue:**

I have a very simple repository. I also created a separate branch with example commit which is breaking the apollo mock provider.

1) Mutation definition is here: https://github.com/developer239/react-apollo-graphql/blob/create-post-integration-tests/src/modules/blog/gql.js#L23

```
export const CREATE_POST = gql`
  mutation createPost($title: String!, $text: String!) {
    createPost(title: $title, text: $text) {
      id
      title
      text
    }
  }
`
```

2) The fake request is here: https://github.com/developer239/react-apollo-graphql/blob/create-post-integration-tests/test/utils/gql-posts.js#L68

```
export const fakeCreatePostSuccess = {
  request: {
    query: CREATE_POST,
    variables: {
      title: 'Mock Title',
      text: 'Mock lorem ipsum text. And another paragraph.',
    }
  },
  result: {
    data: {
      createPost: {
        id: '1',
        title: 'Mock Title',
        text: 'Mock lorem ipsum text. And another paragraph.',
      },
    },
  },
```

3) The component that I am testing lives here: https://github.com/developer239/react-apollo-graphql/blob/create-post-integration-tests/src/pages/Blog/PostCreate/index.js#L24

```
    <Mutation
      mutation={CREATE_POST}
      update={updatePostCache}
      onCompleted={({ createPost: { id } }) => push(`/posts/${id}`)}
    >
      {mutate => (
        <>
          <H2>Create New Post</H2>
          <PostForm submit={values => mutate({ variables: values })} />
        </>
      )}
    </Mutation>
```

4)  The failing test case lives here: https://github.com/developer239/react-apollo-graphql/blob/create-post-integration-tests/src/pages/Blog/PostCreate/index.test.js#L33

```
  describe('on form submit', () => {
    it('should handle success', async () => {
      const renderer = renderApp(<App />, ROUTE_PATHS.createPost, [
        fakeCreatePostSuccess,
      ])
      const { formSubmitButton } = fillCreatePostForm(renderer)
      fireEvent.click(formSubmitButton)
      await waitForElement(() => renderer.getByTestId(POST_DETAIL_TEST_ID))
      expect(renderer.getByTestId(POST_DETAIL_TEST_ID)).toBeTruthy()
    })
  })
```

It seems that I followed all steps from the [official documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/testing/) but I still can't make this work. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the official docs its stated we should add `addTypename={false}` to the `<MockedProvider>`. And when I looked at the error message I could see that the `__typename` was added to the query it was looking for.

Something like:

```
{ Error: Network error: No more mocked responses for the query: query getDog($dogId: ID!) {
  dog(dogId: $dogId) {
    name
    __typename
  }
}
```

So after removing `addTypename={false}` I got another error:

```
Missing field __typename in {
  "name": "dog"
}
```

Now when adding a `__typename` to my mocked response it started working.

e.g.

```
const mocks = [
  {
    request: {
      query: dogQuery,
      variables: {
        dogId: 1,
      },
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        dog: {
          name: 'dog',
          __typename: 'Dog',
        },
      },
    },
  },
];
```

Comment: I will investigate that and approve the answer if it works. 